# parse JSON in android, how to parse

Tags: android, json

I am using openstreetmap to get the current city name. I have the URL sent which is:

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=52.5487429714954&lon=-1.81602098644987&zoom=18&addressdetails=1

I am getting this result as JSON:

```
{"place_id":"62762024","licence":"Data \u00a9 OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http:\/\/www.openstreetmap.org\/copyright","osm_type":"way","osm_id":"90394420","lat":"52.548781","lon":"-1.81626870827795","display_name":"137, Pilkington Avenue, Castle Vale, Birmingham, West Midlands, England, B72 1LH, United Kingdom","address":{"house_number":"137","road":"Pilkington Avenue","suburb":"Castle Vale","city":"Birmingham","county":"West Midlands","state_district":"West Midlands","state":"England","postcode":"B72 1LH","country":"United Kingdom","country_code":"gb"}}
```

how could I use it in my code.

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button123);
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            String url="http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverseformat=json&lat="+currentLatitude+"&lon="+currentLongitude+"&zoom=18&addressdetails=1";
            s = getJson(url);
            if(s!=null){
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(s);
                String exResult = jObj.getJSONObject("SOMETHING")//I don't know what to put here
```

Answer (score 0):

Get values with their tags. Such as:

```
String placeId = jObj.getString("place_id");
String licence = jObj.getString("license");

JSONObject addressJsonObject = jObj.getJSONObject("address");
String houseNumber = addressJsonObject.getString("house_number");
```

**Edit:** BTW this page may help you to understand the structure of any json string. Copy and paste your json string there. http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: Probably you are getting a different response from service. To check that copy your json response (value of s in your case) to the address I've shared. Do you see any value for address?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
String exResult = jObj.getJSONObject("address").getString("city");
```